# Can I use the formula for the centrifugal force to solve this gravitation related exercise problem?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, centrifugal-force, satellites

I have a problem in which I need to find the kinetic energy to put in orbit a satellite already at a height $h$. So far I have worked out that $F_g = F_c$ (gravitational force = centrifugal force) so that the satellite should gain velocity and then substitute it in kinetic energy formula $$ K=\frac{G M_{earth} m_{satellite}}{R_{earth}+h}$$
The problem is that my physics teacher says centrifugal force isn't a force itself because there is no mass creating it, then he doesn't use this formula. Is the general idea of my approach, physically speaking?

Comment: When you say “centrifugal force”, you mean “centripetal force”. Centripetal force is the component of the net force directed towards the centre, which is what you are using here. Centrifugal force is never a real force; it is an illusion created by using an accelerating frame of reference and this “no mass creating it” thing is nonsense. And it has nothing to do with the energy formula in your question. Your energy formula also does not contain velocity, so how can you substitute velocity in it? Please provide more of your working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your teacher is correct. There is no such thing as a centrifugal force. The feeling of being "flung" outwards in circle is due to inertial motion, not a force.

Secondly, even if the $Fc$ term was an outwards-pushing force, it would not work to simply set this force equal to the force of gravity. If they are equal then they balance out as per Newton's 1st law and there'd be no push up to a higher orbit.

---

I think I'd go for a method like this without being sure if there isn't a faster way:

### First, kinetic energy

You are looking for the kinetic energy change. So let's start there.

$$K=\frac12 mv^2$$

The change in kinetic energy between current and new orbit is:

$$\Delta K=K_\text{new}-K_\text{current}=\frac12 mv_\text{new}^2-\frac12 mv_\text{current}^2$$

I presume you know the mass $m$ of the satellite? Then all we need to find are the two speeds.

### Then the centripetal accelerations

Since the unknowns are the speeds, let's find formulas that involve the speed in orbits. That would be the formula for centripetal acceleration (assuming circular orbits):

$$a=\frac{v^2}r$$

Setting this up for each orbit:

$$a_\text{current}=\frac{v_\text{current}^2}{r_\text{current}}\qquad,\qquad a_\text{new}=\frac{v_\text{new}^2}{r_\text{new}}$$

### Finally, the forces

Now we have introduced a new unknown: the centripetal acceleration. Which formulas involve the acceleration? Newton's 2nd law is a good start:

$$\sum F=ma$$

The only force involved during an orbit is gravity $F$ which is always downwards, along with the centripetal acceleration. We input these:

$$F_\text{current}=m\underbrace{\frac{v_\text{current}^2}{r_\text{current}}}_{a_\text{current}}\qquad,\qquad F_\text{new}=m\underbrace{\frac{v_\text{new}^2}{r_\text{new}}}_{a_\text{new}}$$

The gravitational force $F$ is unkonwn. But you mention the formula for gravitational force:

$$F=G\frac{mM}{r^2}$$

where $m$ is satellite mass and $M$ Earth mass. We input this:

$$G\frac{mM}{r_\text{current}^2}=m\frac{v_\text{current}^2}{r_\text{current}}\qquad,\qquad G\frac{mM}{r_\text{new}^2}=m\frac{v_\text{new}^2}{r_\text{new}}$$

And now we have reached a point with no other unknowns than the speeds. One unknown in each equation; this should be solvable. Just input the correct distances $r_\text{new}$ and $r_\text{current}$ and solve for the speeds. And then input those speeds in the kinetic energy formulas we started with. (Note that the distances $r$ are to the centre of the orbit, so from satellite to Earth's *centre*, not just to the surface.)

Comment: +1 Because the reasoning in this answer is good. But I am not sure if it is actually an answer, because the question is still unclear to me.

Comment: @BrianDrake Thanks. Yes, I agree, the question seems to be carrying some more depths that aren't entirely clear as of now. When the OP responds I can adjust if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You mention:
"my physics teacher says centrifugal force isn't a force"

On the subject of whether there is a 'centrifugal force'.

Let me make a comparison.
Let's say you and a companion are taking the time to relish a wonderful sunset. You and your companion would talk about that in terms of the Sun going down. It would be insufferable smugness to insist: "No, actually it's the Earth rotating. The Sun is stationary, the local Earth surface we are standing on is tipping away from the Sun."

Of course, it is in fact the case that it is the Earth *rotating*. If you are discussing some physics with a fellow student then to avoid ambiguity you will state explicitly that the Earth is rotating.

A line of reasoning is valid only if *all* relevant information is taken into account. Of course, when we perform a tabletop experiment we treat the piece of Earth we are standing on as non-rotating. The scope of the experiment does not extend to the entire Earth, hence no necessity to include that information.

When the discourse is about the position of the Sun then the *scope* of the discourse is the *Solar system*. Then the fact that the Earth is orbiting the Sun must be integral part of the discourse.

With the above in place: in particular circumstances the concept of 'centrifugal force' can be the most economical way to communicate what is happening. In conversation just for speed you can talk in terms of 'centrifugal force' as long as both in the conversation know it's not meant literally.

In the case of an orbiting celestial object the gravitational interaction is providing the required centripetal force. Orbital motion is not a force equilibrium case. (As in: a supposed equilbrium of attracting gravitational force and "centrifugal force".)

**Cognitive psychology**

There is however, a psychological dimension here that needs to be recognized. It has to do with how *perception* of gravity works.

The perception of gravity is different from the perception of other ways force can be exerted upon you. Example: let's say someone is tugging your coat. Some parts of your coat will press against your skin, and you notice that.

Gravity however, acts on *all* parts of your body the *same*.

Perception of gravity builds up as follows: when you are standing up your feet have to carry the entire weight of your body, but your pelvis only has to carry your weight from the pelvis up; your neck only has to carry the weight of your head. All parts of your body have sensor cells that report how much *compression* they are sensing. From your ankle bones up to your neck bones there is a gradient in how much they are compressed. That directional gradient, combined with the sensor input of your equilibrium organ, gives rise to the perception of gravity.

That is: our perception of gravity is not a direct perception. Instead evolution has equipped us with a built in system to *infer* the presence of a gravitational force.

That system operates automatically. Wenever we sense this *directional gradient of compression* we cannot *not* infer the presence of a gravitational force.

**On a merry-go-round**

When you are playing on a merry-go-round a centripetal force must be provided to sustain circumnavigating motion. Every body has inertia (pun intended.) Inertia is in a category of it's own. Inertia cannot be categorized as a force. Something can be categorized as a force if and only if it involves a third law force pair.

Now, whether you are clinging on with your hands, or bracing yourself in any way: the *physical sensation* is identical to the sensation of being pulled away from the center of rotation by some centrifugal force.

The physical sensation is identical because inertial mass is equivalent to gravitational mass. (No exceptions to that rule are known.)

This, I believe, is why everybody who first starts thinking about some motion that is going round automatically starts with thinking in terms of a centrifugal force.

My point is: I'm saying that in education it's important not to be dismissive when a student starts with thinking in terms of a centrifugal force.

I argue that to understand why one should *not* go to supposition of centrifugal force is an acquired skill, like learning how to read is a an acquired skill.

Comment: +1 Good explanation of “centrifugal force”, but I think your sunset analogy is a bit problematic. It seems to be universally accepted that the Earth’s surface can be modeled as an inertial reference frame, which is kind of what we are doing when we talk about the Sun moving. But the reference frames that give rise to the phrase “centrifugal force” cannot be modeled as inertial. (The Sun’s movement is usually not what people have in mind when they say the Earth’s surface can be modeled as an inertial reference frame. So this comment might also be problematic. I do not know what to think.)

Comment: @BrianDrake I added paragraphs, addressing your comment. I assert  it should be thought of in terms of scope. To understand the motions of the planets of the solar system we treat the center of mass of the solar system as moving in a straight line. On galactic time scale we understand our Sun to be orbiting the galaxy's center of mass. Tabletop experiment: local scope. Conclusions/reasoning from any experiment are valid only for the extent of the originating scope.

Comment: @BrianDrake One more remark. In your comment to the question you used the qualification: 'it's an illusion'. While that is a common thing to do, I believe that qualification increases confusion rather than addressing it. I believe that whenever inertia is at play it should stated explicitly that it's about inertia. Inertia is forceful; the amount of force involved is described by $F=ma$. It's just that inertia cannot be categorized as a force. Something can be categorized as a force if it involves a third law force pair. Inertia is in a category of its own.

Answer (score 0):

The intuition behind the idea of centrifugal forces is the tendency to balance the forces in a (apparentely) static situation.

It is easy to accept that $F=ma$ when pushing an object and getting accelerating as a result. As the velocity is increasing, it is clearly a non static situation.

But circular movement is different. The distance from the center and the modulus of the velocity are constant, what induces us to intuitively look for an equilibrium of forces to explain that stable configuration. So, to balance the centripetal force, we tend to imagine a centrifugal force, forgetting that the acceleration is not zero.

The key point is to remember that $\mathbf F = m \mathbf a$ is a vector equation, and $\mathbf a = \frac{dv}{dt}$ is pointing to the center. The equation shows that the same must be true for the force. In the case of the question, gravity is the centripetal force, proportional to the centripetal acceleration.